# iPhone -> Linux PPTP

Tags: domain-name-system, pptp, iphone

I have set up a PPTP tunnel on my linux box 192.168.1.10 (LAN is 192.168.1/24)

PPTP settings are: Local/Remote 192.168.2.10 / 192.168.2.100-200.

I can connect to the server with an iphone and can access ip addresses on the lan, but cannot connect to the internet with DNS. I can access the internet with ip addresses.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Do you have an internal DNS server?

Comment: The DHCP which assigns the IP address inside of 192.168.1.x to the iPhone should also assign a DNS server (within the network), which should be capable of internal/external resolution.

Comment: @GregD no, use opendns

Answer (score 3):

If you can use the IP addresses but not the names, it means that the DNS is not working.

Set the following in `/etc/ppp/options` (on the server):

```
ms-dns 208.67.222.222  
ms-dns 208.67.220.220
```

to use opendns, or easier to remember, [Google public dns](http://code.google.com/speed/public-dns/):

```
ms-dns 8.8.8.8
ms-dns 8.8.4.4
```

Those servers are anycasted around the world and are pretty reliable, and also quite fast!

Comment: That was a great explanation, and prompted me to go back and understand what Anycasting is, and why it is used.